# Simplifying the determinant of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1+a_{1}+a_{1}b_{1}+b_{2} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ a_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}+b_{3} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}+a_{3}b_{1} + b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4} + a_{4}b_{1} & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ Show that $$\det(A) = \det\begin{pmatrix} b_{1}-b_{2}+b_{4} & 1+a_{1}-a_{3}+a_{4}\\ -1-b_{2}+b_{3} & a_{1}-a_{2}+a_{4}\end{pmatrix}$$

---

I am not sure how to show this. I tried to perform some row and column operations but could simplify matrix $A$.

Note that for a general matrix of size $(3k+1)\times (3k+1)$, the determinant of $A$ can be written in a similar form. Say for a $7 \times 7$ matrix,

$$A_{7 \times 7} = \begin{pmatrix} 1+a_1+a_1b_1+b_2 & 1+a_1 & 1& 0 &0 &0 &0\\ a_2 + a_2b_1 + b_3 & 1+a_2 & 1 & 1&0&0&0\\ a_3+a_3b_1+b_4 & a_3 & 1 & 1 & 1& 0 &0\\ a_4+a_4b_1+b_5 & a_4 & 0 & 1 & 1&1 &0\\ a_5+a_5b_1+b_6 & a_5 & 0 & 0 & 1&1 &1\\ a_6+a_6b_1+b_7 & a_6 & 0 & 0 & 0&1 &1\\ a_7 + a_7b_1 & a_7 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 &1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\det(A) = \det\begin{pmatrix} b_{1}-b_{2}+b_{4}-b_{5}+b_{7} & 1+a_{1}-a_{3}+a_{4}-a_{6}+a_{7}\\ -1-b_{2}+b_{3}-b_{5}+b_{6} & a_{1}-a_{2}+a_{4}-a_{5}+a_{7}\end{pmatrix}$$

Any thoughts on how to show this in general?

Comment: Oh ok..I have written down the $7 \times 7$ matrix $A$, i see there is a pattern to it

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction. It's clear now.

Comment: Remark: Subtracting column 2 to column 1 doesn't change the determinant and simplifies the matrix.

Comment: I wonder what argument can we use for a general matrix of size $3k+1 \times 3k+1$. I was thinking to use induction but which row and column to take in a general matrix?

Comment: It seems something to do with the power series $\sum a_i x^i$ and $\sum b_i x^i$ ($a_0=b_0=1$) or rather their "sections"  got by averaging at $x,\omega x, \omega^2 x$.

Comment: Can you tell me where is come from? I would to know if it is related to some physic phenomena

Comment: Actually it is analysing the determinants of tridiagonal matrix, when columns are added later to it..it was an observation i saw.. see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522806/inverse-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-all-entries-unity also observe tha tthe later right part of matrix is tridiagonal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for any integer $n\geq 1$ and any numbers $A_1,...,A_n,B_1,...,B_n$ we have
$$
\det\left(I_n+\begin{pmatrix}A_1 & B_1 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
A_2 & B_2 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
A_n & B_n & 0 & \cdots &0 \\\end{pmatrix}\right)=\det\begin{pmatrix}1+A_1 & B_1 \\ 
A_2 & 1+B_2\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The determinant under consideration (for all $n$) is
$$
\det(M+N)=\det M\cdot\det(I_n+M^{-1}N)
$$
where
$$
 M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &\cdots\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots&\cdots \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots&\cdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots&\cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots& \ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\cdots&1\end{pmatrix},\quad
N=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1(1+b_1)+b_2 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
a_2(1+b_1)+b_3 & a_2 & 0 & \cdots &0\\
a_3(1+b_1)+b_4 & a_3 & 0 & \cdots &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
a_n(1+b_1)+b_{n+1} & a_n & 0 & \cdots &0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We have $\det M=1$ and $M^{-1}$ is the matrix whose
first row is $(1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,...)$ and the $(k+1)$th row is obtained from the first by adding $k$ zeros to the left and truncating it to the right:
$$
M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&0&1&-1&0&\cdots\\
0&1&-1&0&1&-1&\cdots\\
0&0&1&-1&0&1&\cdots\\
0&0&0&1&-1&0&\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&1&-1&\cdots\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&\cdots&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
By inspection, $M^{-1}N$ has the 3rd, 4th,... columns equal to the zero vector (as $N$ does so) and therefore we can apply the formula stated in the beginning to obtain
$$
\det(M+N)=\det(I_n+M^{-1}N)=\det\begin{pmatrix}1+A_1 & B_1 \\ 
A_2 & 1+B_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
with
\begin{align}
A_1&=\sum_{j=1}^n i_j(a_j(1+b_1)+b_{j+1}),&
B_1&=\sum_{j=1}^n i_ja_j,\\
A_2&=\sum_{j=1}^n i_{j-1}(a_j(1+b_1)+b_{j+1}),&
B_2&=\sum_{j=1}^n i_{j-1}a_j,
\end{align}
where we set $i_0:=0,i_1:=1,i_2:=-1$ and $i_{j+3k}:=i_j$ for all integers $k$. (To match the matrix in the original question, $b_{n+1}=0$, but the formula is valid for any value of $b_{n+1}$.)

Finally, the constraint on the remainder mod $3$ of the size is not necessary, the formula holds for all $n$.

Comment: Yes but the inverse of tridiagonal matrix doesnot exist if $n$ is of the form $3k-1$, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522806/inverse-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-all-entries-unity

Comment: there is no tridiagonal matrix involved here as far as I can tell

Comment: I can't see the relation with the link, the matrix involved in my answer is identity + strictly upper diagonal (and so, invertible, with explicit inverse) and it is not tridiagonal

Comment: Is the first equation of the answer obvious or is an important consequence of a theorem?

Comment: I think you can still simplify the 2 by 2 matrix at the last line..like $C_1 \rightarrow C_1 - (1+b_1) C_2$

Comment: The first equation follows by Laplace expanding wrt the last row n-2 times. And yes, the final 2x2 determinant can be simplified as you say.

Comment: @Guilio: Very nice answer. (+1)

Comment: @GiulioR any idea on this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4534538/simplifying-determinant-of-a-sparse-matrix

Comment: @GiulioR any ideas on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576505/proving-an-implication-of-two-dimensional-matrix

Answer (score 4):

Remember that $\det$ is a multi linear functional and that if the columns of a matrix $A$ are linear dependent, then $\det A=0$. Hence

$$\det \begin{pmatrix} 1+a_{1}+a_{1}b_{1}+b_{2} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ a_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}+b_{3} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}+a_{3}b_{1} + b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4} + a_{4}b_{1} & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=\det \begin{pmatrix} 1+a_{1}& 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ 1+a_{2} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}& a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4}  & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+\det \begin{pmatrix} a_{1}b_{1}+b_{2} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ -1+a_2b_1+b_3 & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}b_{1} + b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4}b_{1} & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=0+\det\begin{pmatrix} a_{1}b_{1}+b_{2} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ -1+a_{2}b_{1}+b_{3} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}b_{1} + b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4}b_{1} & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=\det \begin{pmatrix} (1+a_{1})b_{1} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ (1+a_{2})b_{1} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}b_{1}  & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4}b_{1} & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ -1-b_{1}+b_{3} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ 0 & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=0+\det\begin{pmatrix} b_{4}& 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ b_4& 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ 0 & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2} & -a_4& 1 & 0\\ -1-b_{1}+b_{3} & 0 & 1 & 1\\ b_{4} & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2}-b_4 & 1+a_{1}+a_4 & 1 & 0\\ -1-b_{1}+b_{3}-b_4 & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ 0 & a_{3}& 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=0+0+\det \begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2}-b_4 & a_3 & 1 & 0\\ -1-b_{1}+b_{3}-b_4 & a_3 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & a_{3}& 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0& 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+\det  \begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2}-b_4 & 1+a_{1}+a_4-a_3 & 1 & 0\\ -1-b_{1}+b_{3}-b_4 & 1+a_{2}-a_3 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0& 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0& 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=\det \begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2}-b_4 & 1+a_{1}+a_4-a_3 \\ -1-b_{1}+b_{3}-b_4 & 1+a_{2}-a_3 \\ \end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=0+\det \begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2}-b_4 & 1+a_{1}+a_4-a_3 \\ -1-b_{1}+b_{3}-b_4-(-b_1+b_2-b_4) & 1+a_{2}-a_3-(1+a_1+a_4-a_3) \\ \end{pmatrix}=$$

$$= \det \begin{pmatrix} -b_{1}+b_{2}-b_4 & 1+a_{1}+a_4-a_3 \\ -1+b_{3}-b_2 & a_{2}-a_1-a_4 \\ \end{pmatrix}=$$

$$= \det \begin{pmatrix} b_{1}-b_{2}+b_4 & 1+a_{1}-a_3+a_4 \\ -1-b_2+b_3 & a_1-a_2+a_4 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Any thoughts on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576505/proving-an-implication-of-two-dimensional-matrix

Answer (score 1):

When looking for transformations to come from
\begin{align*}
\det\begin{pmatrix} 1+a_{1}+a_{1}b_{1}+b_{2} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ a_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}+b_{3} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}+a_{3}b_{1} + b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4} + a_{4}b_{1} & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
to
\begin{align*}
\det\begin{pmatrix} b_{1}-b_{2}+b_{4} & 1+a_{1}-a_{3}+a_{4}\\ -1-b_{2}+b_{3} & a_{1}-a_{2}+a_{4}\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
we observe that we don't have any product $a_kb_1$ in (2).

- So, it's plausible to first try to remove the products by subtracting from column $1$, $b_1$ times column $2$.
- We can simplify column $1$ even more by additionally subtracting column $2$ from it.
- And since it's often convenient to increase zero entries we also subtract column $4$ from column $3$.

> We obtain from (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\det}&\color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix} 1+a_{1}+a_{1}b_{1}+b_{2} & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ a_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}+b_{3} & 1+a_{2} & 1 & 1\\ a_{3}+a_{3}b_{1} + b_{4} & a_{3} & 1 & 1\\ a_{4} + a_{4}b_{1} & a_{4} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}}\\\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad C_1\leftarrow C_1-C_2-b_1C_2\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad C_3\leftarrow C_3-C_4\\\\
> &=\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_1+b_2 & 1+a_{1} & 1 & 0\\ -1-b_1+b_3 & 1+a_{2} & 0 & 1\\ b_{4} & a_{3} & 0 & 1\\ 0 & a_{4} & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\\\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad C_2\leftarrow C_2+a_4C_3\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad C_4\leftarrow C_4+C_3\\\\
> &=\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_1+b_2 & 1+a_{1}+a_4 & 1 & 1\\ -1-b_1+b_3 & 1+a_{2} & 0 & 1\\ b_{4} & a_{3} & 0 & 1\\ \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{-1} & \color{blue}{0}\end{pmatrix}\\
> &=\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_1+b_2 & 1+a_{1}+a_4 & 1\\ -1-b_1+b_3 & 1+a_{2} & 1\\ b_{4} & a_{3} & 1\end{pmatrix}\\\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad R_1\leftarrow R_1-b_4R_3\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad R_2\leftarrow R_2-a_3R_3\\\\
> &=\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_1+b_2 -b_4& 1+a_{1}+a_4-a_3&1\\ -1-b_1+b_3-b_4 & 1+a_{2}-a_3&1\\\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{blue}{1}\end{pmatrix}\\
> &=\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_1+b_2 -b_4& 1+a_{1}+a_4-a_3\\ -1-b_1+b_3-b_4 & 1+a_{2}-a_3\end{pmatrix}\\\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad R_2\leftarrow R_2-R_1\\\\
> &=\det\begin{pmatrix} -b_1+b_2 -b_4& 1+a_{1}+a_4-a_3\\ -1-b_2+b_3& -a_1+a_{2}-a_4\end{pmatrix}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\det\begin{pmatrix} b_1-b_2 +b_4& 1+a_{1}-a_3+a_4\\ -1-b_2+b_3& a_1-a_{2}+a_4\end{pmatrix}}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (2) follows.

Comment: Any thoughts on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576505/proving-an-implication-of-two-dimensional-matrix