# Simplifying the determinant of a given sparse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was thinking about how to simplify the determinant in order to obtain the following equality of determinants. i am not seeing a direct connection between the determinants.

$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
-1+b_{3} & a_2 & a_1 & 1 & 0 &0&0&0&0\\
b_4+b_1 & a_3-1&a_2&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
b_5+b_2&a_4+a_1&a_3-1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
b_6&a_5&a_4&-1&0&0&1&0&0\\
b_7&a_6&a_5&0&-1&0&0&1&0\\
b_8&a_7&a_6&0&0&-1&0&0&1\\
b_9&a_8&a_7&0&0&0&-1&0&0\\
0&a_9&a_8&0&0&0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&a_9&0&0&0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix} = \det \begin{bmatrix} a_1+a_4+a_7 & -1+a_3+a_6+a_9 & b_2+b_5+b_8\\
a_2+a_5+a_8 & a_1+a_4+a_7 & -1+b_3+b_6+b_9\\
-1+a_3+a_6+a_9 & a_2+a_5+a_8&b_1+b_4+b_7\end{bmatrix} $$

I think some row and column operations might be needed. also, any idea how to show this in general?

This is similar to the question: [Simplifying the determinant of a matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528541/simplifying-the-determinant-of-a-matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same strategy as in my previous answer to the linked question should work.

The matrix
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 &0 &1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots \\
0& -1 & 0 &0 &1 & 0 &\cdots \\
0&0&-1 & 0 &0 &1 &\cdots \\
0&0&0&-1 & 0 &0 &\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&-1 & 0 &\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&0&-1&\cdots \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the matrix with entries $M_{i,j} = -\delta_{i,j}+\delta_{i,j-3}$ and has an explicit inverse
$$
M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 &0 &-1 & 0 & 0 &-1&\cdots \\
0& -1 & 0 &0 &-1 & 0 &0&\cdots \\
0&0&-1 & 0 &0 &-1 &0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&-1 & 0 &0 &-1&\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&-1 & 0 &0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&0&-1&0&\cdots \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&-1&\cdots \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
$$
i.e.
$$
(M^{-1})_{i,j} = -(\delta_{i,j}+\delta_{i,j-3}+\delta_{i,j-6}+...)=-\sum_{s\geq 0}\delta_{i,j-3s}.
$$
This can be checked in many ways, for instance by a direct computation of the matrix product. Another hint for this formula for the inverse matrix is given below (see the **Additional comment** below).

Once this is settled, we have to compute the determinant of $M+N$ where $N$ is an arbitrary matrix with only the first three columns different from zero, let me call it
$$
N=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1&0&0&\cdots\\
a_2&b_2&c_2&0&0&\cdots\\
a_3&b_3&c_3&0&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\det (M+N)=\det(M)\det(I+M^{-1}N).
$$
Now, $\det M=(-1)^n$ (calling $n$ the size of the matrices under consideration), and the matrix $M^{-1}N$ has the same structure as $N$, in the sense that its only nonzero columns are the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd ones, for the sake of giving a name to its entries let us denote it as
$$
M^{-1}N=\begin{pmatrix}A_1&B_1&C_1&0&0&\cdots\\
A_2&B_2&C_2&0&0&\cdots\\
A_3&B_3&C_3&0&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that (and here's the crucial step where we reduce it to a $3\times 3$ determinant)
$$
\det(I+M^{-1}N) = \det\begin{pmatrix}1+A_1&B_1&C_1\\
A_2&1+B_2&C_2\\
A_3&B_3&1+C_3\end{pmatrix}
$$
and it remains to compute $A_i,B_i,C_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. This is done using the explicit expression for $M^{-1}$, yielding
\begin{align}
A_1&=-a_1-a_4-a_7-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}a_{1+3s}, &
B_1&=-b_1-b_4-b_7-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}b_{1+3s}, \\
C_1&=-c_1-c_4-c_7-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}c_{1+3s}, \\
A_2&=-a_2-a_5-a_8-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}a_{2+3s}, &
B_2&=-b_2-b_5-b_8-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}b_{2+3s}, \\
C_2&=-c_2-c_5-c_8-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}c_{2+3s}, \\
A_3&=-a_3-a_6-a_9-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}a_{3+3s}, &
B_3&=-b_3-b_6-b_9-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}b_{3+3s}, \\
C_3&=-c_3-c_6-c_9-...=-\sum_{s\geq 0}c_{3+3s}.
\end{align}
(Here we set $a_j:=0,b_j:=0,c_j:=0$ for all $j>n$.)
With some elementary manipulation and matching of the parameters $a_i,b_i,c_i$ in the question this is the $3\times 3$ determinant given in the question.

**Additional comment** about $M$ and $M^{-1}$. Let $\mathcal R$ be the quotient of the ring of polynomials in one variable $x$ by the ideal generated by $x^n$. Then, $M$ represents the linear transformation of $\mathcal R$ induced by multiplication by $x^3-1$, with respect to the monomial basis. The element $x^3-1$ is invertible in the ring $\mathcal R$, with inverse $-1-x^3-x^6-\cdots$ (it is a finite sum due to the definition of $\mathcal R$). Multiplication by this element is represented by the matrix $M^{-1}$.