# Proving an implication of two dimensional matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, determinant

If $A = \begin{bmatrix} x & 1\\ y & 0\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} z & 1\\ w & 0\end{bmatrix}$, for $x,y,z,w \in \Bbb{R}$.

I have observed by considering many  examples of $x,y,z,w$ that:

If all the eigen values of $A^2B$ and $AB^2$ are less than one in absolute value $\implies$ $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$ is not possible.

Any way how to prove it actually?

I am thinking if $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$,  then perhaps it would violate certain assumptions on the eigenvalues of $A^2B, AB^2$?

Explicit forms of matrices:

$A^2B = \begin{bmatrix} z(x^2+y)+xw & x^2+y\\ xyz+wy & xy\end{bmatrix}$

$AB^2 = \begin{bmatrix} x(w+z^2)+wz & xz+w\\ y(z^2+w) & yz\end{bmatrix}$

$AB +A+I = \begin{bmatrix}  xz+w+x+1& x+1\\ yz+y & y+1\end{bmatrix}$

$BA+B+I = \begin{bmatrix} xz+y+z+1 & z+1\\ xw+w & w+1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You mean that the determinants cannot be **simultaneously** negative ?

Comment: yes exactly, both the determinants cannot be simultaneously negative

Comment: Just a quick idea, suppose on the contrary it was true. Then the product of two negative numbers is positive and using the fact that determinate is multiplicative might be good idea. If not, try to factor a matrix out of the product inside and view that determinant as the characteristic polynomial of a matrix evaluated at point.

Comment: Another idea : using Cayley-Hamilton theorem : $A^2$ can be replaced by $xA+yI$ and $B^2$ by $zB+wI$...

Comment: A limit case : $A=\pmatrix{a&1\\a&0}$ with $B=\pmatrix{-1&1\\-1&0}$

Comment: $det(AB+A+I) = 0, det(BA+B+I) = 0$ for the above case

Comment: Could be helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: I've checked by computer that if $y = -x^2/4$ and $w = -z^2/4$ (this is the case when neither $A$ nor $B$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$) then your conjecture is correct.

Comment: I've also verified the conjecture in the case that $y = 0$ or $w = 0$ (this is the case when $AB$ is not invertible), and in the case that $x = 0$ or $z = 0$.

Comment: Yes trying a lot of examples hints that the conjecture is true but I am not sure about how to prove that the conjecture is true

Comment: What about using identities such as: $det(A\left(B+I\right)+I)=1+Tr(AB+A)+det(A)det(B+I)$

Comment: Now posted on MO: [Proof of a matrix implication](https://mathoverflow.net/q/435267).

Answer (score 1):

This has been [proven on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/435689/496009). Making a Community Wiki answer so that it can stop showing up in the unanswered list while avoiding me "taking credit" for someone else's solution.

Comment: The conjecture is known to be true via software and numerical searches but a formal mathematical proof is still not there.. Before posting this question I have mentioned that after trying a lot of examples, I have derived this conjecture but the answers have shown that using softwares the conjecture is true.. And i dont see a formal. Proof.   So the question still remains open.

Comment: There's a big difference between checking a lot of examples (leading to suspecting the statement might be true) vs. using a computer to check cases as part of a full proof. The MO post is a full proof of the statement you asked for, and thus it fully answers the question you've asked here.

If you don't want to accept their answer, you should probably open a new question that links to the old one but adds "I want a *simpler* proof" or "I want a proof that can be fully checked by hand with no computer" or whatever your true condition is.