# How do find the (possible) solution(s) to a tridiagonal matrix consisting only of ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

How would you decide whether a tridiagonal matrix with all ones in the diagonals has only a trivial solution (as matrix b is zero in the equation Ax=b)?

Edit: So, a general solution to an n by n matrix of the following appearance:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  1&  0&  0\\
 1&  1&  1&  0\\
 0&  1&  1&  1\\
 0&  0&  1&  1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

The eigendecomposition of a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/179900/81360). Let $n$ denote the size of the matrix $A$. The equation $Ax = 0$ will have a non-trivial solution if and only if $A$ has $0$ as one of its eigenvalues, which in our case means that there is an integer $1 \leq k \leq n$ for which
$$
1 + 2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1}\right) = 0 \implies \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1}\right) = -\frac12.
$$
Because $\cos^{-1}(-1/2) = 2 \pi /3$, we can conclude that $A$ will have a non-trivial solution for $Ax = 0$ if and only if $n+1$ is divisible by $3$, which is to say that $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

We also know that in these cases, the solution space will be one-dimensional and spanned by the vector
$$
v = \pmatrix{
\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi}{3} \right) & 
\sin\left(\frac{4 \pi}{3} \right) & \cdots & 
\sin\left(\frac{2n \pi}{3} \right)}^\top = 
\\
\frac {\sqrt{3}}{2}\pmatrix{1 & -1 & 0 & 1&-1&0&\cdots & 1 & -1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's compute some determinants recursively. Surely there is some pattern in here that we can exploit.

$1\times 1$
\begin{equation}
|[1]| = 1
\end{equation}

$2\times 2$
\begin{align*}
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
=0
\end{align*}

$3\times 3$ - expanding on the last row, then on the last column
\begin{align*}
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
&=
(-1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0\\
1 &  1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
+
(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  1\\
1 &  1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right| \\
&=
(-1)(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
+
(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  1\\
1 &  1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right| \\
&=
-1 + 0 = -1
\end{align*}

$4\times 4$ - expanding on the last row, then on the last column
\begin{align*}
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
&=
(-1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1  & 0\\
1 & 1  & 0\\
0 & 1  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
+
(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\right|\\
&=
(-1)(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1  \\
1 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
+
(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\right|\\
&=
0+(-1) = -1
\end{align*}

$5\times 5$ - expanding on the last row, then on the last column
\begin{align*}
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
&=
(-1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0  & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1  & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1  & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
+
(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right|\\
&=
(-1)(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0  \\
1 & 1 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
+
(1)
\left|
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right|\\
&=
1
+
(-1)
=
0
\end{align*}

Comment: You might [find this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant) to be useful